# SOLRJ - index info how to query for it

Tags: json, solr, solrj

I found out that when we enter admin page of my SOLR server there is such a request:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/documents/admin/luke?wt=json&show=index&numTerms=0

This request is getting some basic informations about index such as last modified etc. I want to create query using SOLRJ but I can't. My code is very simple:

```
        SolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/documents/admin");

        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery("luke?wt=json&show=index&numTerms=0");

        QueryResponse response = null;
        SolrParams solrParams = solrQuery;
        response = server.query(solrParams);
        logger.error("PING: " + response.getElapsedTime());
        for(SolrDocument doc: response.getResults())
        {
            for(String key: doc.keySet())
            {
                logger.error("KEY: "+key+" VAL: "+doc.get(key));
            }
        }
        logger.error("TEST after");
```

I got error **Problem accessing /solr/docs/admin/select** wich isn't something strange. Should I use simple GET and parse JSON or there is some other way to use SOLRJ for this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the correct url for accessing the solr end point should be:

```
SolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/documents");
```

Assuming the core name for your solr setup is `documents`.

The default handler is `/select` handler.

Comment: The default is `/select`.